# Get 0 for column select if where clause does not match

Tags: sql, jasper-reports

I have the following SQL query in a subreport:

```
select ifnull(sum (commissionDocument.netto), 0) as commissionCreditNoteNetValue,
   ( select ifnull (sum (commissionDocument.netto ), 0)
     from tckopf as commissionDocument
     where commissionDocument.referenzid = $P{document_id} 
       and commissionDocument.btyp = 7) as commissionInvoiceNetValue
from tckopf as commissionDocument
where commissionDocument.referenzid = $P{document_id} 
  and commissionDocument.btyp = 8
```

The problem is that I get an empty report if the `where` clause:

```
where commissionDocument.referenzid = $P{document_id} 
  and commissionDocument.btyp = 8
```

does not match and the other `where` clause match.

```
where commissionDocument.referenzid = $P{document_id} 
  and commissionDocument.btyp = 7
```

1. [SQL Fiddle example if the inner `where` clause match](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/908f7/1)
2. [SQL Fiddle example if both `where` clauses match](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/cdc5d/1)
3. [SQL Fiddle example if the outer `where` clause match](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/c91e7/1)

I forgot to mention, that FoxPro DBF contains the data and is connected via a JDBC driver to *iReport*.

The subreport has only one field with the following expression.:

```
($F{commissionInvoiceNetValue} != null && $F{commissionCreditNoteNetValue} != null)
? ($F{commissionInvoiceNetValue} - $F{commissionCreditNoteNetValue})
: ($F{commissionInvoiceNetValue} != null) ? $F{commissionInvoiceNetValue}
: ($F{commissionCreditNoteNetValue} != null) ? $F{commissionCreditNoteNetValue}
: ""
```

How can I bypass that?

Comment: Can you give us an http://www.sqlfiddle.com/ ?

Comment: ... Is `commisionDocument.referenzid` unique?  Can we get sample starting data and desired results?

Comment: No `commisionDocument.referenzid` is not unique. A lot of records can have the same `referenzid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [changed the query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58673/subtract-values-from-select-in-sql/58717#comment105926_58673) to:

```
SELECT
(   SELECT IFNULL (SUM (commissionInvoice.netto ), 0) AS commissionInvoiceNetValue
    FROM tckopf AS commissionInvoice
    WHERE commissionInvoice.referenzid = 1
        AND commissionInvoice.btyp = 5 )
-
(   SELECT IFNULL (SUM (commissionCreditNote.netto), 0) AS commissionCreditNoteNetValue
    FROM tckopf AS commissionCreditNote
    WHERE commissionCreditNote.referenzid = 1
        AND commissionCreditNote.btyp = 6 )
 AS commissionResult
```

and the field to the the following expression:

```
$F{commissionResult}
```

and now I get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I thin you can fix this by an outer join:

```
select ifnull(sum (cDoc.netto), 0) as cCNValue, CInvNoteVal.Val
from tckopf as cDoc
FULL OUTER JOIN
  (select ifnull (sum (cDoc.netto ), 0) AS Val, referenzid 
  from tckopf as cDoc
  where cDoc.referenzid = $P{document_id} and cDoc.btyp = 7) as CInvNoteVal
  ON CInvNoteVal.referenzid = cDoc.referenzid
  where cDoc.referenzid = $P{document_id} and cDoc.btyp = 8
```

Comment: It does not work, in iReport I get: "`Invalid column or variable: CInvNoteVal.referenzid`".

Comment: What SQL version do you use?

Comment: Don't really know. It's a FoxPro DBF that is used in iReport through a [HXTT JDBC driver](http://www.hxtt.com/dbf/) and it seems to be ["more than SQL92"](http://www.hxtt.com/dbf.html).